# Dynamically created files are not in the solution explorer

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2019

This piece of code creates a new html document, i can see it in the file explorer, i can open it, but is not in the solution explorer (I'm using Visual Studio 2019, and this is a ASP.NET web forms project, if that helps):

```
string fielName = Server.MapPath("~/Created files/" + Name + ".html"); // Works ??

            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fielName);

            tw.WriteLine(@"

            <!DOCTYPE html>

            <html>
            <head>
                <link rel=""stylesheet"" href=""https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"">
                <script src=""https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js""></script>
                <!--Latest compiled JavaScript-->
                <script src=""https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js""></script>

                <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
            </body></html>");

             // close the stream
             tw.Close();
```

I've tried Closing VS and opening it again, and still the files are not in the solution explorer, if there's something code-wise i could do or something else, is very welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: The solution explorer explores the solution, not the file system. If you want a file to be in the solution you need to add it to a project. You *could* programmatically update the `.csproj` file if you really want to, but you would still need to reload the project in Visual Studio before it shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have "Show All Files" option activated in solution explorer? There is an icon button for it at the top of the solution explorer.